# what is the best way to implement a cancel button that sends an order id to the controller and updates the order status attribute to "cancelled"?

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

what is the best way to implement a cancel button on an orders show page. The cancel button simply updates the order's status attributes to "cancelled" in a controller. I would like to carry over the order.id to the controller as each user has many orders.I am currently getting an undefined method 'id' for nil:Nilclass which makes me think the @order.id is not being passed into the hidden-field. Not sure what am doing is the best way to pass the order.id into the controller&welcome any ideas for a better solution

```
<div>


    <% @orders.each do |order| %>
        <%= order.id %>
        <%= order.total %>
        <%= order.user.name %>

        //lots of boring stuff then at the bottom of the page

        <%= form_tag guest_cancel_path, method: :post do |f| %> 
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<% order.id %>" >  
        <%= submit_tag "Cancel ",class: "cancel-button btn wide" %> 
        <% end %>
```

In my controller, I have:

```
def guest_cancel 
    @user = current_user 
    @order = Order.find(params[:order_id]) 
    @order.update(status: 'cancelled')
    redirect_to guest_requests_path, notice: " the order: #{@order} by user -> #{@user} has been cancelled, " 

end
```

then in my routes:

```
post 'guest_cancel' => 'orders#guest_cancel'
```

Comment: What are your `params` in console, when you hit the submit button

Answer (score 1):

It seems you missed to output it `"<%= order.id %>"`

you would need to add this the controller too: `@order.update(status: 'cancalled')`

Comment: I forgot to type that on here, thanks, but I am getting an undefined method 'id' for nil:nilClass even after outputting the order.id

Comment: Just updated the answer .. I thinks it should've been order.id directly .. (inside loop) .. is it working ?

Comment: No it didnt work, I think the problem is that the id is not being passed into the input field   <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="<% order.id %>" >  because the order.id acts as a local variable that cannot be accessed inside the form. Thanks for trying, though

Comment: okay. how about assigning it at each iteration `<% @current_order_id = order.id %>` before entering the form_tag block. Then use `@current_order_id` instead.

Comment: As he said originally, you need an equals sign: `<%= order.id %>` without an equals sign in there, Erb evaluates the order id, but doesn't include it in the HTML output

Answer (score 1):

If you have relation between listening and orders then you should write 

`<% listing.orders.each do |order| %>`

so, orders instead of order.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. That was a typing error here, but I changed my code and updated the question from looping through  each user's  listings and printing all the orders in each listing to just checking all the orders where the user is a guest <% @orders.each do |order| %> but am back to the same problem of not being able to pass the order.id to the hidden-field attribute

Comment: You're welcome, I'm not sure what is exactly happening, can you use something like pry or debugger in your controller to check what's inside params hash?
https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger

Comment: It may be that you have to access order_id like this params[:order][:order_id]

Comment: I checked the hash is empty. I don't think the problem is at the controller. I think the order can not be passed into the form because its not a global variable that can be accessed inside the form. I will probably have to figure out set the order.id to a global variable then use it inside the form like Abdullah suggested or remove the form completely and try to do an ajax post action to send  the id as json or something to the controller which will be too much complexity just to send a simple id to a controller

Comment: I would suggest you to first try with form_for instead of form_tag and use hidden_field instead of regular input with type="hidden".
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field

Comment: This may be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18205875/how-to-access-hidden-field-in-controller-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: Hey, thanks for the last link, it was helpful and for your time and effort. All I had to was use a hidden_field_tag instead. I will upvote your answer